# Difference between image of FT in matlab vs. cuda

Tags: c++, cuda, fft

I am trying to implement a matlab code that I have that does a 2D convolution.

The matlab code first centers the 3x3 kernel in a padded matrix the size of the Image. I do the same thing in my C++ code.

I have outputted my array and the matlab matrix to .csv files and confirmed that they are identical. I then run a forward FFT on each of these. In matlab, the FT image of the kernel looks like you'd expect - basically intense in the middle, radiating out in a circle. However, the CUDA FT image (which i am drawing in matlab after importing it as a csv) looks like an oval.

What can be causing this? It looks almost as if the kernel was not centered in the image, but like I said, I dumped out the padded Kernel data to a csv and used imagesc to see it in matlab, and it looks centered to me, and in fact is the exact same as the padded matlab kernel.

This is the code I used to put my kernel in the center of my padded array:

```
kSize = 3;
halfl = 0.5*(kSize-1);

if(chipW%2 == 0)
    dcW = (.5*chipW) +1;
else
    dcW = round(chipW*.5);

if(chipH%2 == 0)
    dcH = (.5*chipH) +1;
else
    dcH = round(chipH*.5);

dcH--;
dcW--;


for(int i = dcH-halfl ; i <= dcH+halfl ; i++)

{
    for(int j = dcW -halfl ; j <= dcW+halfl ; j++)

    {
        h_PaddedKernel[i*chipW + j] = make_cuComplex(hp_kernel[(i-(dcH-halfl))*kSize + (j-(dcW-halfl))], 0.0);

    }


}
```

kSize is the width of one size of my kernel, chipW and chipH are the width and height of the image i am trying to process

Comment: Check out how cuda displays the actual values. You might need to do some sort of scaling. Matlab works well on floating point values. But Not really sure if Cuda does the same. So probably that might cause the problem in only displaying the FFT.

Comment: when you say scaling, you for sure just mean scaling as in divide by number of elements right? Not actually moving data elements to another place in the array?

Comment: @ Derek, scaling means either multiply or divide. Don't move the points anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things :

- matlab natively computes using double. Is your CUDA code doing the same ?
- matlab displayed tried to scale the values before displaying them, there is some option in plot to prevent this.